# Can I create a .pkg file on windows

Tags: windows, file, packagemaker

I need to create .pkg file from a folder on windows which OSX can understand. I know that .pkg file itself is a folder. But what i need it to host this file on a web server so that it could be downloaded as a single file from a Mac OSX? When I create the .pkg file from a Mac OSX, then as soon as I bring it to Windows it is converted to folder!

Sanjay Arora

Comment: Yes, Windows doesn't recognize .pkg "files" as files. As your question already observes, it treats them as folders. When you transfer that file back to the Mac, everything is peachy-keen. That's because the Mac *does* recognize the .pkg extension as a package file, a special type of folder. What's the question?

Comment: Hi Cody, I need to share my .pkg file from a remote web server so that it could be downloaded as a single file. As it's a folder I was wondering, how can I achieve it. I know I could rather create an archive of it and download the archive. But the Package Maker on OSX does not accept any other file extension other than a .pkg file as Reference Package.